# RSA PKCS#1 V2.1 implementation in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa

Where can I find RSA PKCS#1 V2.1 implementation in C++?
I've found an implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/rsa/), but I'm not sure it fits with that standard.
Can anybody also explain major differences between various implementations of RSA algorithm which may cause inconsistency in action?

Answer (score 3):

The RSA algorithm is a *primitive* you can use for two purposes:

- Confidentiality (that is, public key encryption), or
- Proof of origin (that is, digital signature when combined with a cryptographic hash)

PKCS#1 is **THE** standard mostly everybody refers to nowadays for RSA based encryption and signatures. More in particular, the most recent version of PKCS#1 (2.1) defines four different schemes:

- PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption (for legacy purposes only, nobody should use it anymore)
- OAEP encryption (to be preferred for any new implementation)
- PKCS#1 v1.5 signature
- PSS signature

In other words, when you say "*RSA PKCS#1 V2.1*", you should really refer to any of the schemes above, because a library could implement a subset of the schemes.

The PKCS#1 standard is really well written, so all correct implementations of it are by definition compatible to each other. Since all schemes but the first one rely on cryptographic hashes, you also need to verify that the selected library contains the ones you plan to use (e.g. SHA-256).

I strongly recommended to judge the quality of the library by looking at the set of test vectors (how many there are and where they come from).

Still, a *correct* implementation is not necessarily *secure*. Apart from mundane things like buffer overflows, one should verify that the library takes into account all the most recent attacks targeted at RSA implementations (including at least the most practical [side channel attacks on RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack)). That's difficult to assess, but - for open source libraries - you can get a feeling by looking at the size and the activity of the community, and whether they [publish vulnerabilities](http://cve.mitre.org/) as soon as they are discovered.

Open source C++ libraries like [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) or [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) are a good choice. You may just want to check that they are fast enough for you on the target platform, that their license (respectively BSD and Public Domain) is acceptable, and that they are compatible with your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use studentware libraries for cryptography. They are ill maintained and likely to cause errors. Use well known cryptographic frameworks such as [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) instead. They should claim compatability with standards. You could check if they test against the reference test vectors of the standard; normally something like that exists.

Award extra points if the libraries are FIPS or Common Criteria approved (e.g. OpenSSL is FIPS approved).